# Email being sent too many times

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, email, interop-bridge

I know from my title my question is vague but i will breakdown the question for you people.

So i Have a Workflow which sends email on change of status which in turn sends mail from a 2010 workflow through external users. 
But when i create an item the 2010 workflow gets triggered and sends mail to users even if the condition is not true.
I will be sharing with you my 2013 and 2010 workflow images.
A fact that i had the whole thing running with the same logic but i change the name and description of workflow and it started misbehaving.

Here is the image for the workflow for 2013
[image]
[image]

Now this is my 2010 workflow to send the email
[image]

Could you guys please help me out because this is a big problem for me currently.

Answer (score 0):

In your 2013 workflow, you need to add pause action to wait for several minutes after start 2010 workflow action. This is because that 2010 workflow needs enough time to execute to set the Rejected value to Sent.

If the issue still occurs, you can log all values (log to history list) e.g. Status as on Date, Reject etc. before if condition to check if these values are correct.